# In Android Visibility.GONE is set for parent Layout, one Button is in it. Will Click event fire for that button?

Tags: android, overlay, visibility, onclicklistener

Basically I have a screen. **There are 3 Overlay screens Say A,B and C.** I used fragments. *All 3 screen layouts are in fragment and layouts visibility set `'View.GONE'` by default.* On main screen there is buttons which used to show it.

**A,B and C screens are have 'Save' Button at same palace.**
So A opens first time and it works well. I close A by setting `View.GONE`.
Now i open B overlay screen (by setting `View.VISIBLE`) and try to click `'Save'` button on B screen.

but it does not fire its click event. but when i try to click on same specific corner side of button, it fires. It means last screen A whose Save button is covering,  `'Save'` button of screen B. And that much part is not firing click event for B screen `save` button.

Comment: maybe you have set `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`?

Comment: @agamov No. :) I have set gone. in xml. and setiing gone in java code also. Even i used setEnable(true/false) for buttons also. But its not working. Whichever layout is above it is covering below one.So below one elements, button event is not firing though it is visible.

Comment: If you have 3 different fragments, why are setting the visibility of the main layout to make them appear and disappear? You should use fragment transactions instead.

Comment: @fasteque Ohh sorry my mistake. I have one fragment in which 3 screens. Actually all 3 screens i have created 3 xmls. And used <include > so by mistake i said 3 fragments. I edited it.

Comment: I'd rather use 3 different fragments with transaction. Anyway, if you can post your code (at least xml layouts and where you change visibility) we will be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: @fasteque Thanks. But xml code lines are too long. But i got solution. It is that Parent Layout is set GONE but its child still have effect of its location. So i set each child visibility property GONE. now overlay screen which is opening second have it's click event firing. It means i have to set GONE for each buttons , Only By setting GONE for its Parent Container view will not work

Answer (score 1):

I should not answer my self here. *But i dont want to delete this question also.*

- **Solution :** Only setting parent layout GONE could not worked. So i set GONE for each child to remove its invisible effect on that
  location.

**Explanation in Detail ::**
I had 2 overlay screens on Same activitiy.
Each with left to right entering and existing animation.

With transparent layout. Each screen has Save button at same location.
So which screen is front it only able to handle click event.
1st screen Button covers 2nd screen button.

Though screen no 2 is VISIBLE and no.1 is GONE.

So i set GONE/VISIBLE for not only ParentLayout but also buttons.
Now Button which is visible it can handle event.